# Is it possible to detect if a plugin is activated or not through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, plugins, detection

This way I would normally detect plugins, such as [Flash Player](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash_Player):

```
for (var el in navigator.plugins) {
    if (navigator.plugins[el].name &&
        navigator.plugins[el].name.toLowerCase().indexOf('shockwave') !== -1) {
        console.log(navigator.plugins[el]);
    }
}
```

I'm not looking for a cross-browser solution or want to test if it is the right way or not. What is the way to test if this plugin is active or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both of the other solutions work to find out if a plugin is installed AND is enabled.

There is currently no way to find out if the plugin is installed but is disabled. `Navigator.plugins` does not contain disabled plugins which are still installed.

Answer (score 1):

`navigator.plugins` is an array, so you'd use `for each` in modern browsers and iterate with an index otherwise:

```
function pluginActive(pname) {
    for (var i = 0;i < navigator.plugins.length;i++) {
        if (navigator.plugins[i].name.indexOf(pname) != -1) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

console.log("Flash plugin " +
            (pluginsActive("Shockwave Flash") ? "active" : "not present"));
```

You can not distinguish plugins that are disabled and not present. Bear in mind that you may have to restart your browser before plugin activation / deactivation takes effect.

Comment: It wasn't my question. I know that it an array is. And actually foreach has some performance issues in comparisson with normal for loop. if performance would be important in my question i would change your code to this: `function pluginActive(pname) {
     var i=0, len=navigator.plugins.length;  for ( ;i < len; ) {
        if (navigator.plugins[i++].name.indexOf(pname) != -1) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

console.log("Flash plugin " +
            (pluginsActive("Shockwave Flash") ? "active" : "not present"));`

Comment: @orustam Performance is almost certainly not an issue when you're detecting plugins. This whole code will run in less than a millisecond on every machine and browser. Can you elaborate on why this answer does not address your question? Also, using `for .. in` to iterate over an array only works by accident and can have strange side effects. For example, a browser might store a method name in the `name` property of a method, and thereby confuse your plugin detection.

Answer (score 0):

If the plugin in question is disabled, it won't appear in `navigator.plugins` or be otherwise exposed to the page.

Comment: I've tested it in firefox through plugins tab. i've deactivated all plugins I've ever installed but shockwave flash and quicktime. Iteration through the navigator.plugins show all plugins in the console. It shouldn't actually or not?? That was my question, am i doing anything wrong, or why all of them appears in the console including deactivated plugins??? How could i test it??