# How do I find browser plugins that are installed but not active/enabled?

Tags: javascript, plugins, browser-feature-detection

I have seen solutions to find out if a plugin like reader or flash in installed.

[Is it possible to detect if a plugin is activated or not through JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889412/answer/submit)

However, those work only when the plugin is active. Is there a way to find out if a plug in installed but is not active/enabled at this time?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so, because a deactivated plugin should have no impact to the application anymore. Thats what is meant by "deactivated"