# Modern or Non-deprecated way to detect flash player with js/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, flash

First of all, sorry for ressurrecting this question here.
I've been trying for two days how to reach this job using javascript/jquery and i think i've read all stack overflow and other blogs posts about that, so please, don't mark it as duplicated because I can't use out-dated scripts from 2012 now in 2017.

I've a single page that redirects to a third party e-learning platform where some content needs flash to work. Many users don't care about which software is installed on their machines (what a new, huh) so i need to detect it and show the tipical message "please install/update flash player clicking here", but i cannot find a "modern" script/way to do this, in any place, simplified, if possible.

All scripts i've tried are deprecated or returns false in all browsers, even i've newest version of flash installed and active.

Anny help will be appreciated (except links to older posts or scripts that don't work nowadays, obviously).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: SWFObject - Still working. https://github.com/swfobject/swfobject

Comment: yes, but its **not maintained** since _2+ years_ as of 2017.

Answer (score 5):

There is a simple way to check for Flash since all the **installed and enabled** plugins will be listed in `navigator.plugins;`

Note that if a plugin is installed, but **not enabled**, it will not be detected in the `navigator.plugins` array. There is **NO** way to detect this using Javascript (this [**Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889412/is-it-possible-to-detect-if-a-plugin-is-activated-or-not-through-javascript) which confirms the same).

Having said that, use the following function `isFlashEnabled();` to detect Flash :

```
<html>

<script>

if(isFlashEnabled()) 
{ document.write('Flash is installed (but may need to be enabled)'); } 
else { document.write('Flash is either not installed or disabled'); }

function isFlashEnabled() 
{
    var flash = navigator.plugins.namedItem('Shockwave Flash');
    if (!flash) { return 0; } 
    else { return 1; }
}

</script>

<body> <embed src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/helloworld.swf"> </body>

</html>
```

Comment: @JoëlBonetRodríguez yes, being vanilla JS/native JS, this is **cross-browser compatible**. Tested on Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari (on MacOS, ubuntu) Not tested on IE but I am certain that it should work for IE9+

Comment: Besides, that this is almost the exact same answer I posted some days ago, how did u manage to get it work on firefox? At least for me it doesn't work with the latest version.

Comment: @opp because my answer and your answer are _almost_ the same, but **aren't exactly** the same. In my answer, I am checking for installed plugins in the global plugins array alone, and that's why my solution works for all the browsers, including Firefox (you can try running the snippet on FF to verify)

Comment: In the second code block (from mozilla) I'm checking also only for the named plugin. But never mind! The snippet is not working on my latest FF (v 52.0)

Comment: @opp **this code works**!! I've tested it on Windows Firefox (version 52). I've edited it to have an `<embed>` of SWF for clarity of situation. Save shown code as `.html` and test. Go to `about:addons` and choose _"Never activate"_ (+ refresh html tab) versus _"Ask to Activate"_ (+ tab refresh).

Comment: @VC.One You are right, I just tested it locally and on an IIS. This solution and my code snippet work both with the latest firefox! Before I just tested with jsfiddle, where the code doesn't work. my bad!

Comment: This check even works for modern tools that emulate flash (like https://ruffle.rs). Fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

You can get an array which contains all installed plugins of a browser like this:

```
var plugins = navigator.plugins;
```

Then you can then check if the array contains the flash plugin.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/NavigatorPlugins/plugins:

```
function getFlashVersion() {
   var flash = navigator.plugins.namedItem('Shockwave Flash');
   if (typeof flash != 'object') {
      // flash is not present
      return undefined;
   }
   if(flash.version){ 
     return flash.version;
   } else {
     //No version property (e.g. in Chrome)
     return flash.description.replace(/Shockwave Flash /,"");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try it as soon as possible (when time assigned to this job) and i'll give feedback.

Comment: On firefox i'm getting an error (flash is not defined) on a PC where flash is installed... Do you know why?

Comment: I guess due to security reasons its no longer possible to detect if flash is installed or not on firefox.

Comment: @JoëlBonetRodríguez how did you get the error? I'm not getting any response from Firefox. Just blank page (even after trying `document.write` for feedback text).