# How to check if flash is already allowed by user in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, flash, google-chrome-devtools

I have flash games website, I want to check if flash is allowed by user, if allowed, nothing.. if not allowed, instruction popup or any more..

Comment: See this [**Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42728385/2057709) maybe those Answers can help you.. Also try using search box at top of page.

Comment: PS ;From Chrome 57... there is no _"check if flash is allowed by user"_ they will be asked by browser to enable when they visit your site. For a better chance at autoplay try to embed at minimum width 800 and height of 600.