# How to check if Flash enabled for Napster API playback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, api, flash

I am working with the Napster Web API which requires Adobe Flash Player to be enabled in the browser to play/stream songs from the Napster library. 
Link: https://github.com/Napster/napster.js

If Flash is not enabled, an error is thrown and the player fails to stream the requested track. I would like to detect if Flash is enabled before the user has the opportunity to play a track (in which case there would be an error); and prompt the user to install/enable Flash if not done so already.

Here is my HTML code where I am using "ng-if" statements to assist me in checking for Flash and showing the appropriate features to the user.

```
<div ng-if="has_flash== false">
    Prompt user to install Flash
</div>
<div ng-if="has_flash== true">
    <button ng-click="play_napster_track(song_id)">Play</button>
</div>
```

Here is the code for my Angular controller which contains my function to check for Flash, and the Napster player instantiation and track playback function.

```
var app = angular.module("playlists", []);
app.controller("mainController", ['$scope','$http','$compile','$timeout', function($scope, $http, $compile, $timeout) {


    $scope.has_flash = function() {
        //function to detect if Flash is installed and enabled
        //prompt user to install/enable Flash if not already installed
        //returns a bool
    }

    //instantiates the Napster Web API Player
    Napster.player.on('ready', function(e) { 
        Napster.member.set({accessToken: 'oauth access token'}); // If not set earlier
        Napster.player.auth();
    }

    $scope.play_napster_track = funtion(song_id) {
        Napster.player.play(song_id); //plays a track using the Napster Web API
    }

)};
```

Since I am not sure how to check for Flash, currently users are always presented with the option to play tracks and as previously mentioned, this is creating errors for users without Flash enabled. All input appreciated!

Comment: Where on that [**Napster page**](https://github.com/Napster/napster.js) does it say Flash is required? PS: Changed a tag to `html5` for a wider reach.

Comment: @VC.One When the page is loaded, an icon pops up that says Flash has been blocked (chrome in my case) and asks whether to enable Flash; unless it is enabled before the play_napster_track function is called (used to play a track), the track does not play and an error is logged in the console. I'm not sure where Flash is specified in the Napster page, but Napster is explicit with requiring Flash even on their website.

Comment: Ah, so the Napster Player itself requires Flash? OK I thought you were just getting access to mp3 file ([**example**](https://listen.hs.llnwd.net/g3/8/2/0/7/7/1282977028.mp3)) from JSON response (via API request) then play it via your own custom player (audio tag) etc... **(2)** That pop-up is normal Chrome behaviour nowadays (user must agree to use built-in Flash on a per-site basis but it should not ask for future visits if you said yes).. **(3)** Does [**this method**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42815720/2057709) work for other browsers?

Comment: PS: So is your own page on `https://` server? If not, then maybe it's why Chrome asks your visitors everytime (I never even got a pop-up at Napster site, any track just worked, hence oblivious that Flash was ever involved). Am on Chrome v57 WIN/PC... Also I should have checked your code to notice `Napster.player.play(song_id);` (no worries) but I just saw **API** & **Playback** & found the JSON response method so wondered why Flash is even in this Question about MP3 playback. Hope you find a solution soon.