# Enable default browsers prompt with videojs-flash libary

Tags: flash, video.js

I use videojs libary for flash video. When flash is not supported it doesn't show default chrome "puzzle" icon with 'click to enable flash' title. But it show it's own message "No compatible source was found for this media."

Can I set default browsers behaviour somehow?

example http://output.jsbin.com/tacode/

```
<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls 
    preload="auto" width="640" height="268" 
    data-setup='{}'>
    <source src="http://www.mediacollege.com/video-
       gallery/testclips/20051210-w50s.flv" type='video/x-flv'>
</video>
  <!-- versus -->
<embed src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/helloworld.swf">
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I couldn't find solution with library. Furthermore we add src dynamically...  I check if flash is not enabled as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42815720/4075138) and then insert dummy.swf file to the dom. Default browsers handlers works nice.